# ReactJS - Why key prop not required when conditionally rendering components?

Tags: reactjs

We know that we need to use `key` prop when we are rendering array of elements.

For Example:

```
function Component() {
const data = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
return <div>{data.map((d) => <div key={d}>{d}</div>)}</div>;
}
```

But why is `key` not required when we render elements conditionally using `&&` operator ?

For example:

```
function Component() {
  const data = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  const data1 = data[0];
  const data2 = data[1];
  const data3 = data[2];

  return (
    <div>
      {data1 && <div>{data1}</div>}
      {data2 && <div>{data2}</div>}
      {data3 && <div>{data3}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In both cases number of children or order of children can vary. So, why is `key` only required when we are doing `map` ?

Comment: because in a list if we add element at beginning all elements will be rerendered if we dont use key. Its required for diffing algorithm to check which element was added.

Answer (score 2):

`key` is not required when conditionally using `&&` operator, because using it does not change the number/order of children.

For ex, if `data2` is `null`, it's equivalent to

```
<div>
  <div>{data1}</div>
  {null}
  <div>{data3}</div>
</div>
```

Even if does not render anything, `{null}` still counts as an element in the children, so `<div>{data3}</div>` is still at position 2.

Because children positions are stable between re-renders, there is no need for `key`.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a list of elements in React using map(), the key attribute is essential. React relies on the key to efficiently identify and manage individual elements within the Virtual DOM.

If you don't supply a unique key for each element, React will resort to using the element's index within the array as the default key. However, this approach is not recommended, as it can lead to performance issues and inconsistent behavior when elements are added, removed, or reordered. This is especially true for dynamic lists that can be reordered or altered.

https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys
It's explained here